# 406 error always happening with spring rest controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, controller, request-mapping

I'd like to have your opinion on a error always throwed in my spring boot rest controller. I got the following first controller accepting `reading` requests :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/read/{file:.+}" , method =  RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity myFunction(@PathVariable("file") String file) {

    String[] parts = file.split("\\.");
    String extension = parts[1];
    List<SousBloc> resWord;
    List<SousBloc> resPdf;
    List<CvAvecBlocs> resExcel;

    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

    if(extension.equals("xlsx")){
        resExcel = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/readExcel/"+file, List.class, 200);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resExcel, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else if(extension.equals("pdf")){
        resPdf = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/readPdf/"+file, List.class, 200);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resPdf, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else if(extension.equals("docx")){
        resWord = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/readWord/"+file, List.class, 200);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resWord, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return null;

}
```

There is my Reading Word Controller :

```
@Controller
public class ReadWordController {

    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C:\\cvsUploades\\";

    @Autowired
    ReadWord readWord;

    @RequestMapping(value="/readWord/{file:.+}" , method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity readingWord(@PathVariable("file") String file) throws IOException {

        String path = UPLOADED_FOLDER+file;
        List<SousBloc> sousBlocs = readWord.extract(path);

        return  new ResponseEntity<>(sousBlocs, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

Well this controller works fine and does the job.

Now there is my Reading Pdf Controller :

```
@Controller
public class ReadPdfController {

    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C:\\cvsUploades\\";

    @Autowired
    ReadPdf readPdf;

    @RequestMapping(value="/readPdf/{file:.+}" , method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity readingPdf(@PathVariable("file") String file) throws IOException {

        String path = UPLOADED_FOLDER+file;
        List<SousBloc> blocs = readPdf.extract(path);

        return  new ResponseEntity<>(blocs, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

It is contructed on the same model of the Reading Word Controller but it does not work. In debug, the program works fine until the `return  new ResponseEntity<>(blocs, HttpStatus.OK);` that throws a 406 error null...

Do you know why ?

EDIT: I tried something strange and it worked... I put the following code :

```
@Controller
public class ReadWordController {

    private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C:\\cvsUploades\\";

    @Autowired
    ReadWord readWord;

    @Autowired
    ReadPdf readPdf;

    @RequestMapping(value="/readWord/{file:.+}" , method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity readingWord(@PathVariable("file") String file) throws IOException {

        /*String path = UPLOADED_FOLDER+file;
        List<SousBloc> sousBlocs = readWord.extract(path);

        return  new ResponseEntity<>(sousBlocs, HttpStatus.OK);*/

        String path = "C:\\cvsUploades\\file.pdf";
        List<SousBloc> blocs = readPdf.extract(path);

        return  new ResponseEntity<>(blocs, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

Comment: Mark it  answered

Comment: Not answered, just workaround

Comment: Try changing regex from `{file:.+}` to `{file:\\.+}`